# Unable to export query results as csv in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have an employee database with 1800 employees and 45000 messages in between them. I am trying to export the results of the following query into a csv file by clicking the export option in the neo4j browser.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
'file:///employees.csv' AS line 
WITH line
MATCH(e:Employee{pkey:line.profile_key})-[r:Message]->(b:Employee) RETURN 
e.pkey, b.pkey, COUNT(r)
ORDER BY e.pkey;
```

But its not working. I only get the initial 100 rows.I have also changed the number of rows to 10000 in the browser settings, but then again after the execution of the query my browser stops responding and closes automatically. I am using neo4j community edition 3.2.1 on windows. Is there any other way to export the results other than the browser option in windows? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the APOC procedures and run them from the Cypher shell. Example :

```
neo4j> CALL apoc.export.csv.query("MATCH(p:Part) RETURN p.name","/var/tmp/parts.csv", {});
```

This does require you to setup the apoc plugin and add the following parameter to neo4j.conf

```
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: Hii tom, Thank you for your reply....could you also mention how to setup the apoc plugin in windows

Comment: Sure. If you're using a zip install you've got to put it (get the jar from the apoc site) in neo4j-community-3.2.1\plugins and restart. If your using the exe install, the plugins directory is located at C:\users\youruser\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb\plugins ...

Comment: Hii Tom, I have run the following statement `CALL apoc.export.csv("MATCH(e:Employee) RETURN e.pkey", "c:/tmp/parts.csv", {}); `. I have placed the jar file in the specified folder but still I get a message that reads "There is no procedure...registered for this database instance ".

Comment: Did you restart the database ? That's required to "pick up" the new plugin.

Comment: Hii Tom, I have now restarted the database but I am getting the same error..And I have also placed the jar in this location c:/program files/neo4j CE 3.2.1/plugins folder. But In the second case, I was not even able to start the database..

Comment: No, it's definitely in the C:\users directory (note, its inside the database directory itself). Did you get the correct version (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases/download/3.2.0.3/apoc-3.2.0.3-all.jar) ? After you restart the database, try a CALL dbms.procedures(); to get a list. Do you see apoc procedures in there (should be right at the top) ?

Comment: Btw, apoc.export.csv is indeed not an existing procedure, its apoc.export.csv.query, apoc.export.csv.all, apoc.export.csv.data or apoc.export.csv.graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146988/discussion-between-ram-and-tom-geudens).